# Pop Up Button always has the same value in AppleScript

Tags: applescript, xcode

I have a Pop Up Button in Xcode with multiple choices, they are All, 1, 2 3, etc. to 15.

In my AppleScript code I call it ItemPicker:

```
property ItemPicker : missing value
```

I have made a Referencing Outlet from "ItemPicker" to Delegate. When I use the value later in the code, I do this:

```
set multiple to ItemPicker's stringValue() as string
```

But for some reason, `multiple` is always `1`.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. You have to set it to `indexOfSelectedItem()` instead of `stringValue()`.

So instead:

```
set multiple to ((ItemPicker's indexOfSelectedItem()) as string) as integer
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out Stefan's answer to this question on MacScripter? 
He says to make a handler like this:

```
on didSelectItem:sender
    log sender's titleOfSelectedItem() as text
end didSelectItem
```

Then connect the handler to the selector on the popup button.

Link to MacScripter article: http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=43906